# How to change keyboard key-shift button indicator color in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-library, android-keypad

I want to change `keyboard` `key-shift` `indicator`color. key showed below.

Default color is `green` i need to change it as `red` what i want to do!?

In this indicator glows green i want to change that green color.

[image]

Help me to solve this.

Comment: Have you find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Write your own custom keyboard app. The Keyboard in the SDK samples can provide you with the base code for that.

You cannot control the visual behavior of other keyboards from within your app, which is why you must make your own.

Comment: i wrote my own keyboard but i cant get that indicator color where the called that color

Comment: If you wrote your own keyboard, wouldn't you know where you set the color?

Comment: i extented keyboard view. but where the used color i dont know

Comment: The color is most likely an attribute or an image in the resources or assets. You will have to change that. Can't help you more without knowing which keyboard view you're extending etc.

Comment: ok can u pls tell me some links for creating own layout. it s use full for me